# Delete lines in range from file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have text file with content like below, i want to delete the lines from specific position..
like from `-displayName: "TIBCO_EMS_2"` to `excludeTopics: []`

I tried like below.

```
DP=TIBCO_EMS_2
sed "/- displayName: $DP/,/excludeTopics/d" config.yml
```

But still no luck, is there any right command to use instead of sed.

```
emsServers:

   - displayName: "TIBCO_EMS_1"
     host: "8988.auf.net"
     port: 7443
     protocol: "tcp"
     user: "admin"
     password: ""
     encryptedPassword: "xzID9SbHsQTMkoRSVTGu4g=="
     encryptionKey: "EncryptionKey"
     showTemp: false
     showSystem: false
     excludeQueues: [sample1 sample2]
     excludeTopics: []

   - displayName: "TIBCO_EMS_2"
     host: "8988.auf.net"
     port: 7333
     protocol: "tcp"
     user: "admin"
     password: ""
     encryptedPassword: "d4FqX7O6bZCDs2corcd2eA=="
     encryptionKey: "EncryptionKey"
     showTemp: false
     showSystem: false
     excludeQueues: [sample1 sample2]
     excludeTopics: []
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `awk`:

```
awk -vRS= '!/displayName: "TIBCO_EMS_2"/{print}' filename
```

Without changing original format,

```
awk -vRS= '!/displayName: "TIBCO_EMS_2"/{print}' ORS="\n\n" filename
```

If you want to pass value in variable,

```
DP='"TIBCO_EMS_2"'
awk -vVAR="$DP" -vRS= '{patt="displayName: "VAR} $0 !~ patt{print}' ORS="\n\n"
```

Comment: Hi!!,, It's not updating the file. I tried like as you mentioned. 

DP='"TIBCO_EMS_2"'
awk -vVAR="$DP" -vRS= '{patt="displayName: "VAR} $0 !~ patt{print}' ORS="\n\n" filename

Comment: @SureshchandraJarugula, It won't update original file. To update the original file, `awk '...' origfile > newfile && mv origfile origfile.bak && mv newfile origfile`

Answer (score 0):

You missed the quotation marks.

```
DP=TIBCO_EMS_2 sed "/- displayName: \"$DP\"/,/excludeTopics/d" config.yml
```

Comment: Hi Pii, It's working fine, but one more thing some time the end of the configured section would be sslVendor: , in that case how can i use ''or condition to declare end of the like excludeTopics: or sslVendor:

Comment: - displayName: "Local EMS"
     host: "localhost"
     port: 7222
     protocol: "tcp"
     user: "admin"
     password:
     encryptedPassword:
     encryptionKey:
     showTemp: false
     showSystem: false
     excludeQueues: []
     excludeTopics: []
     sslIdentityFile:
     sslIdentityPassword:
     sslTrustedCerts:
     sslDebug:
     sslVerifyHost:
     sslVerifyHostName:
     sslVendor:

Comment: I want to delete the lines till next face like "- displayName"

Comment: One way would  be to delete upto the empty line. Replace `/excludeTopics/` by `/^$/`.

Comment: if i am using below command, it's removing entire lines under server section.   sed "/- displayName: \"$DP\"/,/^$/d"